# Why isn't this an homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the map 
$$\alpha :[0,2\pi)\longrightarrow S^1$$
$$\alpha(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$$
First of all I know that it can't be an homeomorphism since $S^1$ is compact and $[0,2\pi)$ is not, and a more "topological" reason is that the inverse function tears the points around a neighbourhood of $(1,0)$ and therefore the inverse of $\alpha$ is not continuous. However I could not actually more rigorously show that the inverse isn't continuous. I tried to show that the necessary and sufficient condition for continuity $f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$ but it backfired and instead it looked to me that it held even in neighbourhoods  of $(0,1)$.

How could I show this more directly?

Update:
Let $S=[0,1)$
To show that the inverse of $\alpha$ is not continuous, as @Paul Frost pointed out, is the same as showing that $\alpha$ is not open (or closed). Consider the interval $A=[1/2,1)$; it coincides with its closure in $S$ since $cl_S(A)=cl_{\mathbb{R}}(A) \cap S$ and therefore it is a closed set (this is also further confirmed by the last example in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology#Examples) wiki link) in $S$. $\alpha(S)$ is not closed in $S^1$ an therefore $\alpha(S)$ is not a closed map which means that its inverse is not continuous as we wanted to show. My confusion was about this: if $A$ is closed in $S$ then we must admit that $S\smallsetminus A$ is open in $S$ which to me sounds kinda strange; however I think it is nonetheless correct to say that it is open in S since is the complementary of a closed set. The topology of $S$ (which has the subset topology) is such that both $(0,1/2)$ and $[0,1/2)$ are *open* sets!

Comment: Is your definition of continuity in terms of open sets or epsilon-delta? In either case, inspect the region around the "tear" more closely.

Comment: Pre-images of neighbourhoods of $0 \in S^1$ are not the neighbourhoods of $0 \in [0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: @MaximNikitin But $\;0\neq S^1\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, yeah, I mean $\alpha(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map is a nice example of a continuous bijection which is not a homeomorphism.

You want to show that $\alpha^{-1} : S^1 \to [0,2\pi)$ is not continuous. This is equivalent to showing that $\alpha$ is not an open map (or alternatively, not a closed map).

The set $U = [0,\pi)$ is open in $[0,2\pi)$, but $M = \alpha(U)$ is not open in $S^1$. In fact, $(1,0) \in M$, but $M$ does not contain any open neigborhood of $(1,0)$ because any such set must contain some $U_\epsilon(1,0) \cap S^1$, where $U_\epsilon(1,0)$ denotes the open disk with radius $\epsilon$ and center $(1,0)$.

Comment: But isn't $[0,\pi)$ clopen in $(0,2\pi)$ and not open?

Comment: Apparently no $[0,\pi)$ is not clopen but open (see the update)

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative (almost) one-line proof that does not involve any $\delta-\varepsilon$ work:

If you remove a non-zero point from $[0, 2\pi)$, then the set is not longer connected. But if you remove a point from $S^1$, it is still path-connected, hence connected. So they cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: Yes this is one of the other proofs I could have used along with the compactness of $S^1$, however I particularly wanted to show directly that the inverse of $\alpha$ is not continuous

Answer (score 0):

Take for example the closed set

$$V:=[2\pi/3\,,\,\,2\pi)\subset[0,2\pi)$$

and suppose we denote by $\;g\;$ the inverse of $\;f\;$, meaning $\;g=f^{-1}: S^1\to[0,2\pi)\;$, so $\;g^{-1}:[0,2\pi)\to S^1\;$ , and

$$g^{-1}(V)=\left\{\,s\in S^1\,|\,(\cos t,\sin t)=s\,,\,\,t\in V\,\right\}= \text{ a half closed arc in}\;S^1$$

and this last one is not closed in $\;S^1\;$ , thus $\;g\;$ isn't continuous.

Comment: I would've said that since the complement of $g^{-1}(V)$ in $[0,2\pi)$ is closed than $g^{-1}(V)$ is open in the interval

Comment: @Peterix Thanks to your comment I realized I had a typo there: it is $\;[0,\pi/3)\;$ in the second interval in that union, yet the problem persists. U think I've an idea how to mend that but I shall delete now...